# Moment.js timezones: Problem finding an item in array within date range

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, offset

I have an array of programs. Each of which has start_date and end_date.

I want to find the current running program in the array by checking my current date in the range of each program's start_date and end_date.

The problem is that the programs were added in a specific time zone, but the dates don't have the time zone info on them.

I have tried setting offsets by the time zones that the program is created. But it didn't help.

`const range = moment.range(moment(el.start_date), moment(el.end_date));`

`moment().within(range);` This works well in the timezone that the program was created.

`moment().utcOffset(240).within(range);` I tried to fix the problem like this, but it didn't help.

Comment: Actually I know the timezone. It’s +4

Comment: `+4` is an offset, not a time zone (See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)).  But additionally, please edit your question to give examples of your inputs.  Are they strings or arrays or `Date` objects or something else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to know the timezone that the programs `start_date` and `end_date` should have you can actually add the timezone to them! `Moment-Timezone` has examples [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/adding-a-zone/) on how to add a timezone to a date.